Operators with closed complemented ranges and surjective operators
My questions are in the spirite of Bounded operators with closed complemented ranges.

Let $F$ be a Fréchet space and $A:F\rightarrow F$ a continuous operator such that $A\left( F\right) $ is closed and there is some closed subspace $E\subset F$ such that $F=A\left( F\right) \oplus E$. Is there some neighborhood $V$ of $0$ such that $F=\left( A-\lambda \right) \left( F\right) +E$ for all $\lambda \in V$ ?

Let $F$ be a Fréchet space, $B$ a Banach space and $A:F\rightarrow B$ a continuous surjective operator. If $S:F\rightarrow B$ is a continuous operator, is there some neighborhood $V$ of $0$ such that $A-\lambda S$ is surjective for all $\lambda \in V$ ?

If answers are negative, are there special cases where 1. and 2. holds ?


I have no idea about the topology of the set of continuous operator on Fréchet spaces and I have no clue how to approach this problem. I will be so thankful for your help.

To @PietroMajer

To @M.González.

The answer to $1$ in general is no: a natural example  is e.g. $F:=C^0(\mathbb R),$ with the topology of uniform convergence on compact sets. Take $E:=(0)$, $A$ the multiplication operator by the function $\alpha(x):=e^x$. Then $A$ is an invertible linear operator, it’s inverse being the multiplication operator by $e^{-x}$. For all $\lambda >0$ and all $f\in C^0(\mathbb R)$, the function $(A-\lambda)f=(\alpha -\lambda)f  $  vanishes at $x=\log \lambda$, so that  $A-\lambda$ is not surjective.

Question 2 and 3 seem quite more difficult.

I think 2. holds if the operator $S$ has same kernel as $A$.  @PietroMajer

yes, in this case one is reduced to the case of two Banach spaces

What if we take dual spaces and adjoint operators @PietroMajer ?

in what situation exactly?

In situation 2.
